# Matlab:Efficient assignment of values in a sparse matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm working in Matlab and I have the next problem:
I have a `B` matrix of `nx2` elements, which contains indexes for the assignment of a big sparse matrix `A` (almost 500,000x80,000). For each row of `B`, the first column is the column index of `A` that has to contain a 1, and the second column is the column index of `A` that has to contain -1.
For example:

```
B=  1   3
    2   5
    1   5
    4   1
    5   2
```

For this B matrix, The Corresponding A matrix has to be like this:

```
A= 1    0   -1    0    0
   0    1    0    0   -1
   1    0    0    0   -1
  -1    0    0    1    0
   0   -1    0    0    1
```

So, for the row `i` of `B`, the corresponding row `i` of `A` must be full of zeros except on `A(i,B(i,1))=1` and `A(i,B(i,2))=-1`

This is very easy with a `for` loop over all the rows of B, but it's extremely slow. I also tried the next formulation:

```
A(:,B(:,1))=1
A(:,B(:,2))=-1
```

But matlab gave me an "Out of Memory Error". If anybody knows a more efficient way to achieve this, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code fills whole columns with 1 or -1. That's why you run out of memory (and the result wouldn't be what you want anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) function:

```
m = size(B,1); %// number of rows of A. Or choose larger if needed
n = max(B(:)); %// number of columns of A. Or choose larger if needed
s = size(B,1);
A = sparse(1:s, B(:,1), 1, m, n) + sparse(1:s, B(:,2), -1, m, n);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do this using the `sub2ind` function. This function converts matrix subscripts to linear indices. You should be able to do it like so:

```
pind = sub2ind(size(A),1:n,B(:,1)); % positive indices
nind = sub2ind(size(A),1:n,B(:,2)); % negative indices
A(pind) = 1;
A(nind) = -1;
```

EDIT: I (wrongly, I think) assumed the sparse matrix `A` already existed. If it doesn't exist, then this method wouldn't be the best option.